# How to get back to the current running test on Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

I run unit-tests from Intellij IDEA with "Track running test" option enabled and Filter turned off.
It works fine until I click on some already passed test, after that it stops tracking current running test.

Is there a way to get back to tracking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try switching Filter on and off. You should end up in currently running test. It works for me.

Comment: After some clicking on random places it started to work. Weird.

Comment: I tried it in IDEA 13, worked for me, unless I had some failures between the selected and currently running test.